# Один сервис для нескольких приложений Android

Tags: android

Возник вопрос.
Можно ли создать сервис, который будет устанавливаться отдельно. Вообще не иметь GUI. И постоянно работать.

При этом, 2 отдельных приложения, а то и 3, и более. Могли бы обращаться к этому сервису, и выполнять какие либо действия.

Попадался ли кому нибудь мануал с подобной реализацией? или хотя бы мануал по общению одного приложения, с сервисом.

Comment: теоретически можно, но зачем? есть такая надобность? идея? но что у него может быть общего с другими программами?

Comment: может можно в виде сайта сделать, то есть удалённого? или что за сервис такой нужен и зачем?

Comment: нет. приложение должно иметь доступ к "железу" ниже подробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно.

Если сервис должен предоставлять нескольким приложениям доступ и возможность манипуляции какими-либо данными, посмотрите на [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

Если же сервис должен выполнять какую-то работу в фоне, чтобы другие приложения могли к нему в любом момент обратиться и, например, узнать прогресс выполнения задачи, реализуйте [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) ([тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) можно узнать подробнее). Также, опишите [AIDL интерфейс](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) для возможности взаимодействия с ним.

Comment: Например, сервис должен по запросу, отправлять файл по bluetooth.
В приложении есть кнопка "Отправить" и поле для выбора файла.
при выборе, файл или его адресс отправляются сервису, а сервис уже отправляет.

Как то так. Все описано примерно, для понимания сути

Comment: Для описанной выше задачи, вполне хватит и [BroadcastReceiver][1].

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html